# How to export file properties in csv using powershell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to export a csv-File with File-Properties from some tif-Files.

With this command

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\tifs\ | 
ForEach-Object {$_ | add-member -name "Owner" -membertype noteproperty `
-value (get-acl $_.fullname).owner -passthru} | Sort-Object fullname | 
Select FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Length,Dimensions | 
Export-Csv -Force -NoTypeInformation C:\Test\export.csv
```

I can export a csv just fine. But as soon as I want to add properties like vertical resolution it fails. I don't quite understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell there's no obvious PowerShell/.Net approach to getting additional file meta data.  However. there are some COM based approaches.

1. Check [Scripting Guys](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/)
2. And they reference [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804)

You will still have to correlate the data. I usually do that by building hash table keyed of same values, in you can index the metadata using the path property, then use the FullName property of the file info objects to reference it, so you can the properties.

Comment: That helped tremendously. Thank you. I found a script somewhere else but it didn't work but the things on this site were explained really well. Now I have the csv I need!

Answer (score 3):

In order to get to the "extended" file properties (like Dimension and Resolution metadata) you have to resort to using the Windows Visual Basic [shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/objects) options from inside PowerShell as `Steven` helpfully pointed out. Here is a code sample that should give you the result:

```
$files = @()
$folder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).namespace("C:\tifs") 

# Loop through each file in folder
foreach ($f in $folder.Items()) {
  $a = 0

  # Print all the available properties (for debugging purposes)
  for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++) {  
    if($folder.GetDetailsOf($f, $a)) { 
      Write-Host "Property: $($folder.GetDetailsOf($folder.items, $a))"
      Write-Host "Value: $($folder.GetDetailsOf($f, $a))"
      Write-Host "Index: $($a)"
    }
  }

  # Store data in custom PowerShell object
  $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSOBJECT
  # Fill each property with the file metadata (by index number)
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullName -Value $folder.GetDetailsOf($f, 194)
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CreationTime -Value $folder.GetDetailsOf($f, 4)
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $folder.GetDetailsOf($f, 5)
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Length -Value $folder.GetDetailsOf($f, 1)
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Dimensions -Value $folder.GetDetailsOf($f, 31)
  # Add custom object to a collection
  $files += $obj
}

# Export collection to CSV
$files | Export-Csv -Force C:\Test\export.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: This is great. For my jpg photos, I am surprised the GPs latitude and longitude are not a part of GetDetailsOf(). Any idea how these can be included?